# Where to install applications

Tags: osx, software-installation, directory-structure

I'm a long-time Windows user in the middle of a multi-year personal migration to Linux-based development.  On Windows when I installed an application it got put in the Program Files folder and I'd have the app store the files that I create while using the app in a separate data folder hierarchy that I could back up regularly.

What are the corresponding folders/directories in Linux (OK, I'm really running on a Mac)?

Comment: Mac does things slightly differently from Linux, like their `/Applications` directory.  For learning about general Linux file system organization, take a look at the [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: Sorry - my bad for being unclear.  I'm talking about generic Linux apps like apache tools and downloads (hadoop, cassandra, pig, etc as specific examples).  I do understand about the /Applications folder for Mac-specific stuff. thx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Linux, the [Linux Standard Base](http://www.linuxbase.org/) describes the filesystem layout and where and how applications and their data are installed.

The LSB references the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) (even though it's terribly out of date) for most items in the filesystem.

As a practical matter, you will find that most applications have their program binaries installed in `/usr/bin`, their libraries installed in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`, their shared application data in `/usr/share` and their machine-specific application data in `/var/lib`.

These directories are where the *system* installs applications.

User-installed applications may be placed under `/usr/local`, the conventions for which mirror those for `/usr`, or in directories under `/opt` which slightly resembles Mac OS X's `/Applications` folder, in which each application has a folder directly underneath, and in that folder the directories typically mirror those found under `/usr`.

Comment: And there is `/var/lib/PROGRAMNAME`...